# Xfa.DatasetsNode.OuterXml is empty

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xfa

I am working to populate XFA form of PDF file using ITextSharp.
I need to export the xfa:datasets first, then I can fill my data then import it back to PDF file.

**The problem is, some PDF file, I cannot extract the xfa:datasets**

I use the code below:

```
pdfReader.AcroFields.Xfa.DatasetsNode.OuterXml
```

This is what I got:**

```
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" />
```

**=> No content insides**

However, I can manually come over this by opening the PDF file by PDF Reader, then save it immediately. Then use above code to read **OuterXml** again. Finally, I have full contents.

Comment: For an empty form, the content of `datasets` is optional. That shouldn't surprise you since there is no form data in an empty form. I'm not sure what you expect from people reading this question. You've already answered your own question: Adobe Reader can create the dataless XML file that you expected based on the data description found elsewhere in the XFA stream.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Because I need the xml template. But now, I cannot get the template and I also don't want to open the PDF file, then fill in some words

Comment: In that case, you need to examine the data description and create the XML you need yourself. There is no other way.